# Receive results from Cassandra using linkedlist

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I currently have a linkedlist which contains a list of usernames which I wish to use in a cassandra query. I am trying to get posts from all the users in that linkedlist.

The queries I am currently using are:

`select * from userposts`

and

`select * from userposts where user =?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is user the partition key? If so, you should be able to do:

```
Select * from userposts where user in (val1, val2, val3);
```

Check http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__selectIN for details.